# 90s fantasy novel about a girl on quest with talking pig (I think)

Tags: story-identification, books, humor

I'm looking for a fantasy novel I read in the 90s. Heroine begins the story overweight and has to go on a long quest (don't remember why). Along the way she acquires a group of animal/spirit? sidekicks, including a smartass pig, I think. By the end of her quest she has lost weight - not the main point of the book of course, but it's a detail that sticks out.

I think she developed magical powers during her quest, which she may have been surprised to discover? That's about all I can come up with. Cover was a girl walking in typical fantasy/forest scene with the animals, as I recall. It was a humorous, lighter fantasy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

This is [Pigs Don't Fly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671876015) by Mary Brown, the second book in the [Pigs Don't Fly](http://www.goodreads.com/series/41410-pigs-don-t-fly) series.

> "I was a huge lump of grease, wobbling from foot to foot like ill-set aspic," confesses Summerdai, the heroine of this improbable charmer with the equally improbable title. Because of her girth, the 17-year-old Summer was passed over to replace her mother as the town prostitute. Equipped with a few supplies, a small dowry and a rather ugly ring left by her mysterious father, she sets out. But the ring is actually a bit of unicorn horn that warns her of danger and, most importantly, allows her to communicate with animals. In quick succession she picks up a ratty dog; a badly used horse; a starved turtle; a wounded pigeon; a man who lost both sight and memory after a bump on the head; and a rather curious little pig with tiny bat wings. The seven of them head south to look for the homes of horse, pigeon and man, during which Summer gains much self-confidence and loses much weight while the small pig/bat gets larger, wiser, more mysterious and more lovable.

and

> When her mother, a medieval village whore, dies, Summer is put out of
>   her home so as not to become a "burden on the parish." With only a few
>   coins for her dowry and a ring as relic of the father she never knew,
>   the girl sets out to make her way in the world. The ring enables her
>   to converse with animals, and as she travels she collects various
>   strays, including a mongrel dog, a lost horse, a broken-winged
>   messenger pigeon, a tortoise, and a strange, winged pig. She also
>   rescues a blind and amnesiac knight. While searching for her charges'
>   homes, Summer names and nurtures them and with them encounters good
>   and bad people and a dangerous ghost. Although their homecomings are
>   not as perfect as she would have liked, most of Summer's friends
>   eventually have them. After the pig's dramatic transformation, Summer
>   is left to face life alone. Yet she has grown from a self-described
>   "fit and ugly" child into a slim, beautiful, and capable woman.

[image]

Comment: Pigs Don't Fly - that's it!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @booknerd - Don't forget to click the accept button to indicate that this was the right answer - ["***How to Accept an Answer***"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hsiv.gif)

Comment: To quote Ray Stevens: "But it was toooo late."